# How to make a personal facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make a facebook application that would do something on my own timeline. I can't understand facebook's own manual about this so i'm not really sure how things work there, so i'm hoping someone can clarify things here. I don't want anyone installing that application or somehow abusing it to post things on my timeline in my name. What steps should i take to prevent these things if possible?

Comment: Just run a check when the user logs in to make sure its your user id and no one elses.

Comment: @TommyCrush Could you please give an example? I'm not sure what you mean by "logs in". Do you mean the auth dialog that users use to install the app or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond what you have learned yet, you can use the php-sdk to authenticate and then check the visitors user id.
*"i will edit in code as we discover what you are trying to accomplish, action wise."*

### php sdk example.

```
        // init php sdk here.  
        // check if we have a user
        // call api to get info about use
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');  

        // if we have a user, we can use that user id as a wrapper to filter content. 

if($user_profile[id]==='000000000'){ 
        // 000000000 is your facebook id for this example.
        // i am logged in, and only i can see this.
        // get some info, make a few posts, add photos etc; here.    
}
```

### cURL example

when you curl 'me', it ensures that it is the current session user, then when you compare that to your actual user id, you can gate "so to speak" content that only you can see and use.
cURL'ing to the me connection is only needed to create gate, you can do all your other curl calls after you know it is you doing it.

```
http://anotherfeed.com/curl.api.php?objid=me
```

here is an example, when i curl me, it looks for a logged in user, if there is an access token *which for this example i excluded*, it will return an array with my "me" info including my id.

Hard coded i will use `$me=$curlresults[id]` which is my user id returned by the session call.

to gate i simply

```
$me=$curlresults[id]
if($me==='myfacebookuserid'){
// do my other curl calls here, i know only i can see this.
}
```

### **Full cURL example.**

1. get your user access token for your app from the token tool below, store it somewhere safe so you can pass it in via url param or session param.... https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/
2. add your facebook user id where it says myfacebookuserid
3. to secure this you will need to pass the access token in with post, get or session.
4. for this example we will use the get method.

`yourpage.php?user_token=youruseraccesstoken` is how it is passed in this example.

---

```
$access_token = $_GET['user_token'];
$build = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?'.$access_token.'';
function GetCH($url){
$ch=null;
if(!$ch){
$ch = curl_init();
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "".$url."");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);    
$return=curl_exec($ch);
 if(!curl_errno($ch)){
return $return;
 }else{
$fb_fail=curl_error($ch);
return $fb_fail;
}
curl_close($ch);
unset($ch);
};
$returned=GetCH($build);
$locs=json_decode($returned, true);
$meid=$locs[id];
if($meid==='myfacebookuserid'){
    // do my other curl calls here, i know only i can see this.
}
```

Comment: OK i'm still very much confused. Sorry ... I don't use any SDKs - just plain calls to graph api. Here's what i do: a) i call "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?" to get a token. b) if i have a valid token, i call "https://graph.facebook.com/MY_PROFILE_ID/foobar" to perform something on the timeline. In which place exactly should i perform those checks and what's from stopping anyone else from calling these 2 URLs manually?

Comment: Are you using cURL to make the calls to the profile?  The direct call to the api with an access token should not work for any other user. 
Using the php sdk you can avoid any security issues, since all the transactions are performed server side.

Comment: Yep, i'm using CURL with PHP. I was hoping there would be an easy fix, cause i really dislike using SDKs, libraries and frameworks where i only need less than 1% of their functionality.

Comment: i have never cURL'ed "me" variable before, let me run a few calls and see if a wrapper can be made.  It should work if you are authenticated to your domain, since curl will pass all session info.

Comment: I don't cURL "me" variable. If you look in my first comment - i use MY_PROFILE_ID instead. That's where i see a security issue. Also i use the auth dialog on a simple browser and the resulting token is then sent into a file on the server-side.

Comment: when you curl me, it ensures that it is the current session user, then when you compare that to your actual user id, you can gate "so to speak" content that only you can see and use.
cURL'ing to the me connection is only needed to create gate, you can do all your other curl calls after you know it is you doing it.

Comment: I think i've tried CURL'ing to "me", but couldn't really figure out how that worked so i sticked to using my profile id. I guess this is not where the problem lies though. Anyone else can still use a URL with my profile ID instead of "me". I think facebook should protect me from this because the URL still uses a token. But is this really the case? Am i the only one who can authenticate and get the token for my app? If so - then, as you stated, there should not be a problem calling these URLs directly from server anyway.

Comment: no, see you are supposed to hard code the me in the curl request and compare that to your id, staticly.  No one will be able to spoof your user id, unless they actually log into your facebook account.

i will edit in the rest of the code and steps needed to follow in a few.

Comment: I feel so stupid now ... Querying /me does give me info about the current access token so i could check for that. But can someone use their own token to write something on my timeline by CURLing to the same url and specifying my profile id? The permissions my app requests are "publish_stream,read_stream,offline_access"

Comment: your right, i just tested this with a browser that was not logged in and it returned my data correctly with my own token.  I guess that is why facebook says never expose your secret or your token.

so from this i am guessing that you will either have to use the php sdk to gate your content or pass the token in as needed using post or get variables as to not have it static to the user.

Comment: Thanks for all your patience :) I guess it was a litle unclear what the access token actually does. Your CURL example illustrates that clearly. Thank you again.

Comment: the access token itself is a string that links you to your app and your app to the api.  example, my user token for one of my app contains this info.


App ID: 
135669679827333 : Another Feed
User ID: 
732484576 : Shawn E Carter
Issued: 
Unknown
Expires: 
1364382000 (in 23 minutes)
Valid: True
Origin: Unknown
Scopes: manage_pages read_stream user_groups

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. I've accepted your answer, but this whole discussion was as useful as the answer itself. Have a great day!